# What is (was) this component at ZD102 (top left, next to powered serial connector)

Tags: power-supply, transistors, diodes, identification, surface-mount

[image: photo of PCB]

Part at ZD102 is overloaded with too much current and blown.

It's three legged, with two legs on the south side and 1 on the top.

The left side (white in the picture) is blown and has since crumbled away. There are now  clearly three metal legs. I cannot identify any markings nor polarity. ZD102 appears to be a unique location.

I would like to identify and then source the part to solder in place. Or something equivalent. Or something I can salvage from other electronics. There doesn't appear to be any other damage to the motherboard.

This is a Wacom digitizer II UX-0608-R from mid 1990s.  DC 9-12v 0.10A.

Appreciate your time.

Comment: Probably a Zener Diode.

Comment: Reasonable that ZD would be Zener Diode, but three legs?

Comment: It could have been 2 diodes in 1 package.

Comment: Go google SOT23 zener diodes.

Comment: Thanks guys. Looks promising. Would you hazard a guess at what spec's given the input voltage of 12v and 100mA.

Comment: No guesses from me. You can buy a replacement pad for $25 from ebay so is it worth the bother/hassle?

Comment: Because shipping to New Zealand is another $55 :/

Comment: It's often possible to find the schematic for many commercial boards, which would tell you what it was. Even if it's not the exact model. I've used these to repair TVs and stuff before.

Comment: The unit is still working?

Comment: In the upper right should be a voltage stabilizer chip IC102, can you read the markup so we can figure the diode value? I agree with Andy, it's an overvoltage protection Zener diode. The voltage should be higher than 12V but lower than maximum input allowed for IC102

Comment: Thanks for taking time. I haven't tried it since.  I need to source to exact power supply.  The IC at 102 is a TA7805F.

Answer (score 1):

TA7805F can handle up to 35V input voltage. I would remove the diode or use a continuity tester to see if the diode is parallel to the 12V power supply.

Take care, the diode might be shorted so better remove-it from the board.

If it was a Zener it should be with cathode to 12V and anode to ground and a breakdown voltage higher than than maximum voltage of the power supply but lower than the maximum input voltage for any component powered from 12V line.

It seems that the board is double sided so it should be easy to follow the 12V line to see where it goes. I suspect that it goes only to TA7805F and some filtering capacitors and you can read that rated voltage.

If the power source is reliable you can put just a simple diode keeping only the reverse voltage protection which I suspect that it is the source of the fault.

The later revisions of the board have a diode in series with the 12V line which leads me to the conclusion that reverse voltage is a common source of failure for this device.

Comment: +1 thanks  The board actually continues to work. I tried the same power supply (12v 1A) and have success.  What happend is now clear: The polarity was + over neg. The adapter I have has a reversable plug, but the default is neg over +. The plug, whilst fitting, was also slightly too large so only made contact briefly as it went in, and not when it was completely secured. I switched the plug end (this adapter comes with a selection) and have a snug fit.  The power light is on and the pad works fine.  I will attempt to source the correct part and replace.